# AWS Key management solution

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, permissions

My company has a server which has an up-to-date clone of a git repo which contains scripts to do with deploying components to AWS. These scripts need to source AWS access keys which they do like so `source ~/.aws_keys/${KEY_NAME}`

We control which apps can be deployed by making a symlink to the actual key. For example:

`-deploying a lambda called DevLambdaName
-looks for a key called ~/.aws_keys/DevLambdaName which is a symlink to ~/.aws_keys/masterkey`

This is fine and works however it is from the home directory of a user (called c2dev) which exists to perform these scripted tasks.

Now as a part of making changes to these scripts I need to run my WIP versions from my own branch which is cloned to a folder in my home dir. This means the scripts go looking for access keys in `~/.aws_keys/` in my home folder, which is fine because I have access keys but it means I have to create a symlink to my master key for every test app which is a bit of a pain.

The keys must also have similar permissions to ssh keys (700 on folder, 600 on files)

What I want is so my scripts look at the c2dev users keys dir.
I have tried:

- Wildcard symlink (i.e. `ln -s masterkey Dev*`)
- Symlinking the folder (i.e. `ln /home/c2dev/.aws_keys/ /home/myuser/.aws_keys/`)
- Setting up an rsync command on a crontab to clone the keys to my keys dir every minute

Nothing seems to work so far, I think because of the permissions on the key files/folder. Help?